# Webpage jumping after using anchorscroll and http.get

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my index.html

```
<body ng-cloak>   
<div id="main">                        
<!-- angular templating -->              
<div ng-view=""></div>{{scrollTo}}
</div>
```

I have a top menu where I'm using anchors. Top Menu is generated from json files.

Part of top menu json File :

```
   {
"menu": "About Me",    
"hrefs": "#/about",
"show": "true",
"menuitem": [
  {"submenu": "Research", "addresstoredirect": "#about?scrollTo=research"},
  {"submenu": "Education", "addresstoredirect": "#about?scrollTo=education"},
  {"submenu": "Career Awards", "addresstoredirect": "#about?scrollTo=careerawards"},
  {"submenu": "Visited Institutes", "addresstoredirect": "#about?scrollTo=visitedinstitutes"},
  {"submenu": "CV", "addresstoredirect": "#about?scrollTo=cv"}
]
```

},
Here is method for anchorscroll :

```
mainApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams,$timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {   
        if ($location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo)) {
        $timeout(function() {
            var hashId = $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
            $anchorScroll();
            //TODO
        },3000);
        }});
    });
```

Each view also contains dynamic content downloaded from json files for example here is aboutView controller :

```
  mainApp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope, $http,$routeParams,$localStorage){
      if ($localStorage.message === "ENG")
      {                             
            $http.get('../app/assets/json/abouttxtEng.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.aboutTexts = data;
      })}
```

And aboutView.html

```
        <h1>About View</h1>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>            
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>{{aboutTexts[0].aboutString[0]}}
        <p>{{aboutTexts[0].aboutString[1]}}
        <p>{{aboutTexts[0].aboutString[2]}}
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>{{aboutTexts[1].aboutString2[0]}}
        <p>{{aboutTexts[1].aboutString2[1]}}
        <p>{{aboutTexts[1].aboutString2[2]}}
        <a name="research"></a>
        <div id="research">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>This is research section of about page</h3>
        Research                    
        <p>{{aboutTexts[2].Research[0]}}
        <p>{{aboutTexts[2].Research[1]}}
        <p>{{aboutTexts[2].Research[2]}}
        </div>
        <a name="education"></a>
        <div id="education">
```

And last piece of the storry. Part of abouttxtEng.json file :

```
            [{
            "aboutString": 
            [
            "aboutText1ENG",
            "aboutText2ENG",
            "aboutText3ENG"
            ]
            },
            {
"aboutString2": 
            [
            "aboutText4ENG",
            "aboutText5ENG",
            "aboutText6ENG"
            ]
            },
            {
"Research" :
            [
            "ResearchText1ENG",
            "ResearchText2ENG",
            "ResearchText3ENG",
            "ResearchText4ENG"
            ]
            },
            {
```

So the problem is when I remove timeout from $rootScope.$on and click any anchor on topmenu, "jump will be executed site will be positioned correctly, but after a while http.get will return aboutText1ENG etc. and page will go down. When I used timeout ( everything is fine ) but 3 seconds is just my assumption. What if http.get will work slower etc. Maybe there is a way to wait before executing jump after http.get will finish ?
I have second solution for that, just in case. I can put whole content in *.js files and load it in the beginning in index.html, but it is good for small amount of content, for bigger it is not. Can sb can help me out ?
P.S Don't bother about html 
 it's just a tests.